# How can I put a String from xpath to an enricher url

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

i need a GET Parameter to an Enricher. This Parameter I want get from the body of the Message with xpath. But it don't want to work. What do I wrong?

```
.enrich("localhost/getArticle.php?ArticleNumber="+xpath("//POSITION/ARTICLENUMMER[@TYPE='IN']/text()"), new addArticleStrategy())
```

But the URL which was called is:

```
http://localhost/getArticle.php?ArticleNumber=XPath%3A+%2F%2FPOSITION%2FARTICLENUMMER%5B%40TYPE%3D%27IN%27%5D%2Ftext%28%29
```

How can I get the value from xpath, not the xpath string?

Thank you

Update:

Full Route:

```
from("activemq:in")
.enrich("localhost/getArticle.php?ArticleNumber="+xpath("//POSITION/ARTICLENUMMER[@TYPE='IN']/text()"), new addArticleStrategy())
.to("file://C:/temp/")
```

Update 2:
I try it with evaluate:

```
from("activemq:in")
    .enrich("localhost/getArticle.php?ArticleNumber="+xpath("//POSITION/ARTICLENUMMER[@TYPE='IN']/text()").evaluate(getContext(), body().convertToString()), new addArticleStrategy())
    .to("file://C:/temp/")
```

But i Get the Error:

```
No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.camel.builder.ValueBuilder to the required type: org.w3c.dom.Document with value body
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use dynamic URL with enrich. Try using [recipientList](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html) instead

Edit:

I have not tried it (sorry possible typos) but it should look like this

```
XPathBuilder articlexpath=xpath("//POSITION/ARTICLENUMMER[@TYPE='IN']/text()").resultType(String.class);

from("activemq:in")
.enrich("direct:getArticle", new addArticleStrategy())
.to("file://C:/temp/");

from("direct:getArticle")
.setHeader("ArticleNumber", articlexpath)
.recipientList(simple("localhost/getArticle.php?ArticleNumber=${header.ArticleNumber}"));
```

Comment: Can you help me how? A recipentList("localhost/getArticle.php?ArticleNumber="+xpath("//POSITION/ARTICLENUMMER[@TYPE='IN']/text()")).enrich(new addArticleStrategy()) not working

Comment: publish the full route please

Comment: See Update in my Question

Comment: Sorry, this don't work. I don't get the result from the request in the AggregationStrategy. There is an empty Body. The URL-Build work now!!!!